# Insert Trigger for Non null columns in SQL Server

Tags: triggers

I have a followed table:

**JobSkill**

```
CreatedByID not null, 
CreatedDate not null, 
ModifiedByID not null, 
ModifiedDate not null
```

I need to insert a record by procedure and trigger.
`CreatedByID` and `ModifiedByID` are inserted through procedure.

I need to create trigger for inserting `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate`.

When I am executing insert method in MSSQL, I am getting this error.

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedDate', table 'One91.dbo.JobSkill'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Can anyone help me in this issue pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with that in one step SQL try to fill all 4 columns, but you provide only 2 values, for `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate`. Because all columns have NOT NULL, SQL cannot leave columns with missing values.

There is a two solution:

1. Change columns `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate`  as NULL, so in procedure they will be NULL, but with trigger you will fill it.
2. `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` can stay as NOT NULL columns, but you must create **DEFAULT** constraint which will assure that columns to be filled in procedure with some default values (or fill manually with some arbitrary values in procedure), and then update them with trigger.