# Doesn't SQL Server have a BEFORE INSERT trigger?

Tags: sql-server

For Microsoft SQL Server, isn't there a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger? I see an `AFTER` and an `INSTEAD OF` but not just a before. I just have a computed value that I want the server to fill in on the `not null` column of the inserted row.

`instead of` is problematic due to Entity Framework issues.

I'm not asking to make the column NOT NULL or provide a simple default. I'm asking for a BEFORE INSERT trigger like many other SQL languages provide.

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? Example structure and data? and What you have tried to do already?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help.  Imagine the table has colums A, B, and C, and I pass in A and B on an insert statement.  In PostgreSQL for example I could create a BEFORE INSERT trigger so that C was automatically set to a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Trigger for Non null columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655043/insert-trigger-for-non-null-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate as that doesn't answer the question.  I don't want the value `not null` and there's not a simple `default` that can be set.  Is the answer simply "No, MSSQL does not have a BEFORE INSERT" trigger like other SQL languages?

Comment: Well if thats the case, your question would be better suited on [dba.se]

Comment: What can't you do wtih a `instead of` trigger that you can do in a `before insert` trigger?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server `BEFORE` trigger is called `INSTEAD OF` trigger. It is just a different syntax.

It is executed before the `INSERT` happens and allows you to intercept the `INSERT` and provide different values for the row(s).

See [CREATE TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) docs:

> INSTEAD OF 
>   Specifies that the DML trigger is executed instead of the
>   triggering SQL statement, therefore, overriding the actions of the
>   triggering statements. INSTEAD OF cannot be specified for DDL or logon
>   triggers.
>
> At most, one INSTEAD OF trigger per INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement can be defined on a table or view. However, you can define
>   views on views where each view has its own INSTEAD OF trigger.